# Display products of specific category on homepage stencil theme

Tags: themes, bigcommerce

How to display limited products of specific category on homepage bigcommerce with **stencil theme**? i want to show some categories like. u can see in my code below:

```
<main class="page-content">
    <h2 class="page-heading">T-Shirts On Sale</h2>
    <span class="viewall"><a href="/t-shirts-on-sale">View More</a></span>
    <ul class="productGrid productGrid--maxCol3" data-product-type="t-shirts-on-sale">
        {{#each products}}
        <li class="product">
            {{>components/products/card theme_settings=../theme_settings}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <h2 class="page-heading">Hoodies On Sale</h2>
    <span class="viewall"><a href="/hoodies-on-sale">View More</a></span>
    <ul class="productGrid productGrid--maxCol3" data-product-type="hoodies-on-sale">
        {{#each products}}
        <li class="product">
            {{>components/products/card theme_settings=../theme_settings}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <h2 class="page-heading">Polos Shirts On Sale</h2>
    <span class="viewall"><a href="/polos-shirts-on-sale">View More</a></span>
    <ul class="productGrid productGrid--maxCol3" data-product-type="polos-shirts-on-sale">
        {{#each products}}
        <li class="product">
            {{>components/products/card theme_settings=../theme_settings}}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</main>
```

Comment: I am using **Cornerstone 2.1** free theme in bigcommerce..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a way to fetch products from a specific category with existing handlebars helpers. You could inject context to a page with product IDs and use that to create product cards such as:

An example of injecting IDs to the category page (not the home page as you specified)

In assets/js/theme/category.js, this add the following:

```
constructor(context) {
    super();

    console.log(context.productIds);
}
```

And in templates/pages/category.html, add:

```
{{inject "productIds" (pluck category.products 'id')}}
```

For the home page, you will need to make changes to assets/js/theme/home.js instead of category or use the API and a separate server (not the utils API, but the API documented at bigcommerce.developer.com) to make a call to a category and provide IDs/product info.